# Reloading the scene cause the admob ads to reload, Is this OK?

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob

I am looking to integrate admob interstitial and banner in Unity.The ad shows well but I have some questions.

I do the method **RequestBanner()** and **RequestInterstitial()** in the **OnStart()** function, and show the ads when the game is over.

When I restart the game, the **OnStart()** method will be called again, and another ad request will be send. I found this will cause the memory increase by about **10MB**. If I add some limits to requset the ads only once, I found that the interstitial is not show when the game is over.

**The two question is:**
1. If i just request banner ads only once, Will the banner auto refresh?
2. How to set the interstitial ads during the unity script time?

The official docs have no ideas about this, and I can't find any useful demos.

Comment: I had a similar issue working with admobs a while back. I also found that It was necessary to request a new interstitial for every ad that I was going to show. But what you want to do is to try and keep using the same Ad (do not request a new one) until it has been seen. Which means, you will have to keep the state of the Ads even if the Object that has this Behavior is destroyed. And if a player has seen the ad, then you can request a new one. Just have a boolean to be set true/false depending if the user sees the gameover or not.

Comment: @KarlPatrikJohansson    Thanks for your advice. But what about the banner? I can set the refresh rate of banner on [admob](https://apps.admob.com), Does that means I don't need to request a new banner?

Comment: The Refresh-rate is only for how frequent the content of the ad should be updated. It still counts as one request, so if its been shown the same ad cannot be requested to be shown again. So you still have to request a new banner ad.

Comment: @KarlPatrikJohansson    then I need to destory the adView(banner and interstitial) and the adRequest to reduce the memory usage when the scene is reload?

Comment: Check out https://developers.google.com/admob/games , they tell you to destroy all the ads after being used. To make sure you avoid any memory leak